# Writting excel doc with multiple columns

Tags: excel, mongodb, python-2.7, datetime

Hi guys I'm getting a strange error here, not sure what the problem is. Unfortunately there are so many possibilities that I cant figure it out.I have a number of time strings that I am returning from a database. and I want to put them into an excel spread sheet with some randomly generated values. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated :)

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses042.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Add a bold format to use to highlight cells.
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})


# Write some data headers.
worksheet.write('A1', 'Facility', bold)
worksheet.write('B1', 'Type', bold)

# Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
expenses=[]
for T in list1:
    FM = random.randint(0,13)
    RUL = random.randint(1,365)
    SL = random.randint(0,4)
    S = str(T['value'])
    expenses= (['rent', S])
    print expenses

# Start from the first cell below the headers.
row = 1
col = 0

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for item, cost in (expenses):
    worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost, money)
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```

OUTPUT

```
runfile('C:/Users/123/Documents/emerson/CSVFILE.py', wdir='C:/Users/123/Documents/emerson')
Extracting all files from MongoDB
['rent', '24-08-2016 14:59:08']
['rent', '24-08-2016 14:59:08']
['rent', '21-08-2016 6:59:08']
['rent', '21-08-2016 6:59:08']
['rent', '22-08-2016 4:59:09']
['rent', '22-08-2016 4:59:09']
['rent', '23-08-2016 7:59:12']
['rent', '23-08-2016 7:59:12']
['rent', '21-08-2016 7:55:40']
['rent', '21-08-2016 7:55:40']
['rent', '24-08-2016 7:57:06']
['rent', '24-08-2016 7:57:06']
['rent', '24-08-2016 16:56:49']
['rent', '24-08-2016 16:56:49']
['rent', '23-08-2016 8:56:59']
['rent', '23-08-2016 8:56:59']
['rent', '21-08-2016 12:55:38']
['rent', '21-08-2016 12:55:38']
['rent', '24-08-2016 23:59:16']
['rent', '24-08-2016 23:59:16']
['rent', '24-08-2016 14:59:08']
['rent', '24-08-2016 14:59:08']
['rent', '21-08-2016 6:59:08']
['rent', '21-08-2016 6:59:08']
['rent', '22-08-2016 4:59:09']
['rent', '22-08-2016 4:59:09']
['rent', '23-08-2016 7:59:12']
['rent', '23-08-2016 7:59:12']
['rent', '21-08-2016 7:55:40']
['rent', '21-08-2016 7:55:40']
['rent', '24-08-2016 7:57:06']
['rent', '24-08-2016 7:57:06']
['rent', '24-08-2016 16:56:49']
['rent', '24-08-2016 16:56:49']
['rent', '23-08-2016 8:56:59']
['rent', '23-08-2016 8:56:59']
['rent', '21-08-2016 12:55:38']
['rent', '21-08-2016 12:55:38']
['rent', '24-08-2016 23:59:16']
['rent', '24-08-2016 23:59:16']
Exception Exception: Exception('Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.',) in <bound method Workbook.__del__ of <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x0AD755B0>> ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-132-bfb0167086a1>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/123/Documents/emerson/CSVFILE.py', wdir='C:/Users/123/Documents/emerson')

  File "C:\Users\123\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\123\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/123/Documents/emerson/CSVFILE.py", line 237, in <module>
    for item, cost in (expenses):

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: the code doesn't match the error...

Comment: not sure if there was a mistake, but i just ran it again (now) and then copied over the code and error again to make sure

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. What's in `dates`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you overwrite `dates` in your loop each time. So when you iterate on the list it doesn't work because it's a mere list, not a list of couples. First iteration yields `"date"`, that cannot be unpacked into 2 variables.

First define `dates` list as empty, then for each iteration append the list.

```
expenses = [] # you're doing that all right
# Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
for T in list1:
    ...
    expenses.append(['date', 1234])
```

now you're able to iterate on the couples and unpack the values.

Comment: i was trying to simplify the problem when i posted it and I think I made some mistakes. Now Ive just put up the code that im actually using the the whole output. I tried what you said but I think I didnt get it right. Could you have a quick look again :) thanks sooo much

Comment: edited to change `dates` to `expenses`. My answer still holds.

Comment: can you do a copy/paste? because your retyping has bugs. Check my answer (do a copy paste)